# oItem_Reply stops working after cancelling the message window

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to use this macro that I "stole" from the interweb. (At least I'm honest...)

It adds a keyword to the subject line when replying to an email.

It works as intended when sending an email but when I cancel the message window the function stops triggering until I restart Outlook.

Why does it behave like that? I have tried to debug it without any luck...
Can anyone help me sort this out?

**The Code in ThisOutlookSession**

```
    Option Explicit
    Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
    Private WithEvents oItem As MailItem
    Private bDiscardEvents As Boolean
    '//slipstick.me/44b0w

    Private Sub Application_Startup()
       Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
       bDiscardEvents = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub oExpl_SelectionChange()
       On Error Resume Next
       Set oItem = oExpl.Selection.Item(1)
    End Sub

    ' Reply
    Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

       Cancel = True
       bDiscardEvents = True

       Dim oResponse As MailItem
       Set oResponse = oItem.Reply

    ' add the fields here
       oResponse.Subject = "keyword " & oResponse.Subject

       oResponse.Display

       bDiscardEvents = False
    Set oItem = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you're getting the error; there could be a few issues - it could be to do with cancelling at the beginning of the sub or using 'Set oItem = Nothing'. Also bDiscardEvents doesn't appear to do anything...

Try the following:

> In ThisOutlookSession

```
Private Sub olItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    If AddKeywordToReply(olItem, "Test:") = True Then Cancel = True
End Sub
```

> In a module

```
Function AddKeywordToReply(oItem As MailItem, KeyWord As String) As Boolean
    AddKeywordToReply = False

    If oItem.Class = olMail Then
        If Not oItem.sender Is Nothing Then
            Dim oMsgReply As Outlook.MailItem
            Set oMsgReply = oItem.Reply
            oMsgReply.Subject = KeyWord & " " & oItem.Subject
            oMsgReply.Display
            Set oMsgReply = Nothing
            AddKeywordToReply = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Oh - I just remembered about Outlook; if it runs into an error or if the code is altered often macros/VBA will no longer run and it requires a restart of the program to restart the VBA. I assume it is a protection measure.

Comment: Thanks @Flephal! I also found this out by myself. The bDiscardEvents did nothing so it could be removed, and 'Set oItem = Nothing' deselected the mail item in the Explorer so it did not trigger next time. If I selected the item manually again, the script triggered without need to restart Outlook.